# how to display data from database in html not using session

Tags: php, html, session, echo

I want to know if there is a way to show/display data from database in html without using session..For examle i have a function `SelectMember` that will select a member from member table then i want to display the details of this member in html as echo. Is there a way to do this without using session?I was able to do it with session but as much as possible i dont want to use session in this time..The function i am talking about is from a separate page that i include in the index of html.In the html is where i want to display the detail. Any suggestion is appreciated

i tried calling the function in the html then i put the variable in echo but the variable in undefined

question is how to fix the undefined variable problem without using session

`update`

```
function EventMember(){
    global $dbh;
    if(!empty($_POST['membername'])){
        $membername = trim($_POST['membername']);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM member WHERE mem_name = ?") ;

        $stmt->bindValue(1,$membername);
        $stmt->execute();
        $selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($selected_row){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $selected_row['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['name'] = $selected_row['mem_name'];
            $_SESSION['age'] = $selected_row['mem_age'];
            $_SESSION['address'] = $selected_row['mem_address'];
            $_SESSION['sex'] = $selected_row['mem_sex'];

            //$memid = $selected_row['mem_id'];
            //$memname = $selected_row['mem_name'];
            //$memage = $selected_row['mem_age'];
            //$memaddress = $selected_row['mem_address'];
            //$memsex = $selected_row['mem_sex'];
            header("Location: searchresult.php");
            exit;
        }else{
            echo "No member found";
        }
    }else{
        echo "name is empty";    
    }
}   



<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="name">name</label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30" value="<?php echo $memname;?>">
    </td>
```

if i uncomment the `$memname` in database side and use it it will be undefined but if i use `$_SESSION['name']` it will show result so how to fix this

Comment: you have mentioned html is it .html or PHP page?

Comment: php or html is it possible if possible how?

Comment: learn first the difference of PHP and HTML. how they differ and limitations. it will answer your question.

Comment: i use php to get data then html to show the ui part the i use html to display all the user interface so that is why i use html to show the data i want to echo the data in html

Comment: Hazy question... I answered it but please refer to the help docs on writing proper questions.

Answer (score 0):

Another Update: So you want to send the data to another page without using sessions...

The easiest way to do this would be to change your header() statement to contains get parameters. But you cannot do this if the data is sensitive...

```
header("Location: searchresult.php?name=".$selected_row['mem_name']);
```

And then on the second page, just use `echo isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";` - make sure to sanitize the data though.

Other than that, you're going to get more complicated with how you're trying to do this - if the above does not work for you, I'd highly recommend you approach this differently.

...

Update: Now that code is provided, I'm adding this to my original answer...

You get an undefined error because you are outside of the scope of the variable you're trying to access. You need to move the html up into the if statement. I did this for you but you should format it better with the echo statement.

Also, you previously had a header() command in that if statement. This will NOT work if you don't use session or something else so that the page you redirect to can access the variable's value.

```
if ($selected_row){

    echo '<tr>
<td valign="top">
    <label for="name">name</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
    <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30" value="'.$selected_row['mem_name'].'">
</td>';

        } else {
            echo "No member found";
        }
    } else {
        echo "name is empty";    
    }
}
```

...

Old Answer:

You retrieve the data without sessions, unless you store the data in session and call to that.

You don't *need* to access it via session, though it's better to store it somewhere (like...session) instead of querying the database repeatedly.

Comment: if i dont use session then the variable will be undefined always that is the problem i want to understand how to fix

Comment: Please post your current code. If you're performing a mysql query and getting the returned data, then the variable will not be undefined.

Comment: it the php side it is defined but when in html it is undefined wait for update i will post code

Comment: @I--I I updated my answer according to the edits you made to your question along with the code you posted.

Comment: i am checking it sir i will be back on you on this..this is code is in the html not the databse side right..i mention above that these two files are separate did  you take it into consideration?the select statement is in crud.php while the echo is in index.php

Comment: You need to combine the two files if you don't want to use session, or you have to send the data to the other page. The first option seems more plausible - I think the second option may be a little advanced for your current understanding of php and forms and such.

Comment: i wanted the second option because it is how i started the project i have many query in the crud.php and then the result is showed in index.php can you show me a sample code for this option?

Comment: @I--I the answer has been updated. If the new answer does not work for you, then you need to approach this differently.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use session for retrieval of the data. Session is only to store data for the application level access.